# Browser uses response from a no-cache request on subsequent request

Tags: google-chrome, caching

When making a request to the server with cache cleared, I use the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to try and ensure the response cannot be used in subsequent requests. The request and response headers are as such:
[image]

However, upon making my next request, this time not clearing the cache beforehand, it appears to have used the cache for the response instead of sending the request to the server, despite `no-cache` being specified in the previous request. The headers are as such:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How do I ensure the response from the first request cannot be used for subsequent responses? I thought that was what `no-cache` was for, but I'm new to the world of caching. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timestamp as a query parameter to your request. This will make sure each request is unique and will not get you cached response. This is called cache busting